# Why does this loop seem convoluted and verbose?

Tags: javascript

The loop below builds an HTML string using the object literal `obj_fav`, which holds a list of favorites.

Because the HTML string can be appended in multiple places, `ns_tag` namespaces the DOM ids to make sure they are unique.

This is somewhat besides the point.  I feel the loop has poor logic.  It works fine, but I find it hard to read and feel that is is poorly written.  But I can't put my finger on why that is.

```
// $A.someIndex() implements array.prototype.some

// create favorite pane strings
$A.someIndex(obj_fav, function (val) {
    previous_id = current_id;
    current_id = this.A.ns_tag + selector + val.tag;

    // new tag found, close previous and open new
    if ((previous_id === undefined) || (previous_id !== current_id)) {

        // populate tag array
        this.A['tag_array' + selector].push(current_id);
        tag_string = tag_string + this.composeTag(current_id, selector);
        if (previous_id !== undefined) {
            favorite_string += '</div>';
        }
        favorite_string = favorite_string +
            '<div class="bookmark_page toggle_display_none" id = "' + current_id + '_page">';
    }

    // add set of favorites between page tags

    favorite_string += this.composeFavorite(val, selector);
}, this);
```

this snippet is contained in this klass:

```
/*******************************************************************************
**SArcmarks
*/


    var SArcmarks = $A.klass({

        Name: 'SArcmarks',

        // namespacing helps to prevent name clashes        // base_location_id_subdivisions        // there are 2 prefixes and one suffix

        A: {
            // namespace suffix             base:                    'udt'          loc:                     null,
            ns_tag:                  'udt_',
            ns_tag1:                 'udt_1_',
            tag_array:               [],
            tag_array1:              [],
            prev_page_el:            null,
            prev_tag_el:             null,
            but_text:                null,

            // toggles
            toggle_display_none:     'toggle_display_none',
            toggle_display_inline:   'toggle_display_inline',
            toggle_tag_active:       'toggle_tag_active',
            toggle_tag_lazy:         'toggle_tag_lazy',

            // morphing
            class_a:                 null
        },

        E: {
            hold_arcmarks:           '#hold_arcmarks',
            hold_tags:               '#hold_tags',
            aba_but_del:             '#aba_but_del',
            bookmark_link:           '@bookmark_link'
        },

/******************************************************************************/

        update: function (obj_fav, fav_el, tag_el) {
            var favorite_string = '',
                tag_string = '',
                current_id,
                previous_id,
                selector;

            if (fav_el) {
                selector = 1;
            } else {
                selector = '';
            }

            // create favorite pane strings
            $A.someIndex(obj_fav, function (val) {
                previous_id = current_id;
                current_id = this.A.ns_tag + selector + val.tag;

                // new tag found, close previous and open new
                if ((previous_id === undefined) || (previous_id !== current_id)) {

                    // populate tag array
                    this.A['tag_array' + selector].push(current_id);
                    tag_string = tag_string + this.composeTag(current_id, selector);
                    if (previous_id !== undefined) {
                        favorite_string += '</div>';
                    }
                    favorite_string = favorite_string +
                        '<div class="bookmark_page toggle_display_none" id = "' + current_id + '_page">';
                }

                // add set of favorites between page tags

                favorite_string += this.composeFavorite(val, selector);
            }, this);

            // close last tag

            favorite_string = favorite_string + '</div>';

            // if atleast one favorite/tag

            if (this.A['tag_array' + selector][0]) {
                if (!fav_el) {
                    this.E.hold_arcmarks.innerHTML = favorite_string;
                } else {
                    fav_el.innerHTML = favorite_string;
                }
                if (!tag_el) {
                    this.E.hold_tags.innerHTML = tag_string;
                } else {
                    tag_el.innerHTML = tag_string;
                }
                this.initPane(selector);
                this.flip($A.el('#' + this.A['tag_array' + selector][0]));
            }
        },

/******************************************************************************/

        composeFavorite: function (val, selector) {

            // add selector
            if (val.favicon === null) {
                val.favicon = 'arcmarks/images/image_null_50.png';
            }
            return '<div class = "am_hold" id = "' + val.id + selector + '">' +
                     '<img name="bo_im" id="' + $A.addU(val.id + selector, 'a') +
                     '" class="bookmark_image" src="' + val.favicon + '">' +
                     '<a target="_blank" name="bookmark_link" class="bookmark_link" href = "' +
                      val.url + '" id="' + $A.addU(val.id + selector, 'b') + '">' + val.title + '</a>' +
                   '</div>';
        },

/******************************************************************************/

        composeTag: function (current_id, selector) {

            // selector
            return '<p class="single_tag toggle_tag_lazy" id = "' + current_id + '">' +
                    current_id.slice(this.A['ns_tag' + selector].length) + '</p>';
        },

/******************************************************************************/

        // add listeners to tag(<p>) elements
        initPane: function (selector) {
            $A.someIndex(this.A['tag_array' + selector], function (val) {
                var self = this;
                $A.el('#' + val).addEventListener("click", function () {
                    self.flip(this);
                });
            }, this);
        },

/******************************************************************************/

        // flip page(<div>) | tag(<p>) given a tag

        flip: function (tag_element) {
            var page_element = $A.el('#' + tag_element.id + '_page');
            $A.addClass(page_element, this.A.toggle_display_inline);
            $A.addClass(tag_element, this.A.toggle_tag_active);
            if (this.A.prev_page_el && (tag_element.id !== this.A.prev_tag_el.id)) {
                $A.addClass(this.A.prev_page_el, this.A.toggle_display_none);
                $A.addClass(this.A.prev_tag_el, this.A.toggle_tag_lazy);
            }
            this.A.prev_page_el = page_element;
            this.A.prev_tag_el = tag_element;
            $A.log(page_element);
        },

        // insert favorite(<div>) given user input

        insertFavorite: function (obj_fav) {
            var tag_id = this.A.ns_tag + obj_fav.tag,
                div_el,
                html_string = this.composeFavorite(obj_fav),
                page_el = $A.el('#' + tag_id + '_page');

            div_el = $A.HTMLToElement(html_string);

            if (!page_el) {
                page_el = this.insertTagAndPage(tag_id);
            }
            $A.eachChild(page_el, function (iter) {
                if (iter === null) {
                    page_el.appendChild(div_el);
                    return true;
                }
                if (div_el.id < iter.id) {
                    page_el.insertBefore(div_el, iter);
                    return true;
                }
                if (iter === page_el.lastChild) {
                    page_el.appendChild(div_el);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            this.flip($A.el('#' + tag_id));
            return div_el;

        },

/******************************************************************************/

        // insert page(<div>) | tag(<p>) given a tag id

        insertTagAndPage: function (tag) {
            var par_el,
                div_el,
                hold_tags_el,
                hold_arcmarks_el,
                self = this;

            hold_tags_el = this.E.hold_tags;
            hold_arcmarks_el = this.E.hold_arcmarks;

            par_el = $A.createElement('p');
            par_el.innerHTML = tag.slice(this.A.ns_tag.length);
            par_el.className = "single_tag";
            par_el.id = tag;

            // insert the tag(<p>)

            $A.eachChild(hold_tags_el, function (iter) {
                if (iter === null) {
                    hold_tags_el.appendChild(par_el);
                    return true;
                }
                if (par_el.id < iter.id) {
                    hold_tags_el.insertBefore(par_el, iter);
                    return true;
                }
                if (iter === hold_tags_el.lastChild) {
                    hold_tags_el.appendChild(par_el);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            par_el.addEventListener("click", function () {
                self.flip(this);
            });

            div_el = $A.createElement('div');
            div_el.className = "bookmark_page";
            div_el.id = tag + "_page";
            div_el.style.display = "";

            // insert the page(<div>);

            $A.eachChild(hold_arcmarks_el, function (iter) {
                if (iter === null) {
                    hold_arcmarks_el.appendChild(div_el);
                    return true;
                }
                if (div_el.id < iter.id) {
                    hold_arcmarks_el.insertBefore(div_el, iter);
                    return true;
                }
                if (iter === hold_arcmarks_el.lastChild) {
                    hold_arcmarks_el.appendChild(div_el);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return div_el;
        },

/******************************************************************************/

        // delete a favorite(<div>) given a link

        deleteFavorite: function (link_el) {
            var self = this,
                div_el = link_el.parentNode;
            $(div_el).toggle("explode", function () {
                if (div_el.previousSibling === null &&
                        div_el.nextSibling === null) {
                    self.deleteTagAndPage(div_el);
                }
                $A.removeElement(div_el);
            });
        },

/******************************************************************************/

        // delete tag(<p>) and page(<div>) given a favorite sub-element

        deleteTagAndPage : function (div_el) {
            var page_el = div_el.parentNode,
                tag_el = $A.el('#' + page_el.id.slice(0, -5)),
                hold_el = $A.el("#hold_tags");
            $A.removeElement(tag_el);
            $A.removeElement(page_el);
            $A.eachChild(hold_el, function (iter_el) {
                if (iter_el) {
                    this.flip(iter_el);
                    return true;
                }
            }, this);
        },

/******************************************************************************/

        morph: function (callback) {
            var i = 0,
                button = this.E.aba_but_del;
            if (this.A.but_text === 'Done') {
                this.A.but_text = 'Delete';
                this.A.class_a = 'bookmark_link';
                while (this.E.bookmark_link[i]) {
                    this.E.bookmark_link[i].removeEventListener("click", callback);
                    this.E.bookmark_link[i].className = this.A.class_a;
                    i += 1;
                }
                button.innerHTML = this.A.but_text;
            } else {
                this.A.but_text = 'Done';
                this.A.class_a = 'bookmark_delete';
                while (this.E.bookmark_link[i]) {
                    this.E.bookmark_link[i].addEventListener("click", callback);
                    this.E.bookmark_link[i].className = this.A.class_a;
                    i += 1;
                }
                button.innerHTML = this.A.but_text;
            }
        }

    }, true);
```

Comment: Can you briefly summarize what the loop is supposed to do?  Anecdotally, I feel that this can be solved simply with a well-placed bit of jQuery code.

Comment: It builds an HTML string from an object literal to be appended to the DOM.

Comment: Yes, but what's the input (the relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) HTML) and what's the expected/desired output..?

Comment: `obj_fav` is an array of objects, each object holds the what you need to make a bookmark, each array element is referenced using `val`, for example `val.tag` holds what the user tagged the bookmark as.

Comment: `favorite_string` holds what will be assigned to the innerHTML attribute, causing the browser to render the object.

Comment: Sometimes code simply needs to be a little clunky. That said, it seems that you have objects that are serialized to HTML. It would seem like it would be nice if your objects were instances of some "class" that managed their own serialization. I'd think it would clean things up a bit, but I don't know what else is involved there.

Comment: none of my code is 'clunky', hence why this bit disturbs me, I remember when I wrote it, I just wanted things to work, and they did, but I felt like it was patching a flat tire with saran wrap instead of buying a new tube.

Comment: I didn't mean that as an insult. It was meant as a synonym for your observation that it's *"hard to read"* or *"convoluted and verbose"*. Not all code is sexy. Just a fact of life. Describing what it does with comments is always helpful for when you return to it later.

Comment: If it does what it is supposed to do, there are no performance problems, and it is unlikely to ever require maintenance, then it's not broken and you don't need to fix it.

Comment: Well, I'm updating the `klass` as another part requires maintenance and I work on a `klass` by `klass` basis.  I'll post the entire klass below, just a sec.

Comment: Wouldn't the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site be more appropriate for this question?

Comment: There's an opportunity cost, that's all.  Time you spend tweaking code that already works is time that you can't spend writing new features, or reducing other, more pressing kinds of technical debt.